# How can I describe a "deleted" AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In our AWS account, I've found a lot of instances with ImageIds that I can't fetch through the DescribeImages action. I assume they've been deregistered or deleted. But it still matters to me what that image *was*.

Is there any way I can pull the description for an image I can't launch anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is likely to be Windows AMIs that have been deprecated.

I have noticed that AWS keeps older Linux AMIs available, since they can be updated with `sudo yum update`. However, Windows AMIs seem to be deprecated after Patch Tuesday updates -- presumably to reduce the likelihood of people using Windows without updated patches.

Once an AMI has been deprecated, it is **not possible** to retrieve information about them.

Comment: I've been waiting patiently for another answer, but it doesn't look like one is coming. Rats. Thanks for the info.